# Redux MapDispatchToProps not functioning

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm new to Redux and I'm trying to get this base model working so I can quickly work on a small personal project, I set everything up and have no errors but I'm trying to test and my function doesn't work so I was hoping someone could point out what I've missed.

I've followed multiple different tutorials and each has a different approach so that has me lost a bit so I apologize for that.

My store.js looks like so

```
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

I've used a combineReducers in my index.js in reducers folder and the auth: points to the authReducer.js file, which is this

```
const INIT_STATE = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
  isLoggedIn: "false"
};

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE:
      console.log(action);
      return {
        isLoggedIn: action.value
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Now What I'm aiming for is to have a button that changes that "IsLoggedIn" initial state to a true string instead of a false, I've went into my actions folder and made an authActions.js which looks like so

```
import { IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE } from "../actions/types";
import store from "../store";

export const isLoggedInChange = value => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE,
      value
    });
  };
};
```

And Finally I want to show you my component page which is showing all this, It's looking like so

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import styles from "./Landing.module.css";
import { isLoggedInChange } from "../../actions/authActions";

class Landing extends Component {
  makeTrue = () => {
    isLoggedInChange("true");
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.background}>
        <button onClick={this.makeTrue}>MAKE TRUE</button>
        {this.props.isLoggedIn}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  isLoggedInChange: value => dispatch(isLoggedInChange(value))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Landing);
```

Can you tell if I dropped anything making this? why is the button not changing the store state? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here. You're calling your action creator directly not `props.isLoggedInChange`

```
  makeTrue = () => {
    this.props.isLoggedInChange("true");
  };
```

And you need to spread the old state inside your action

```
case IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE:
  console.log(action);
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggedIn: action.value
  };
```

> Isn't the point of my `mapDispatchToProps` to be able to use the function right away as I was doing

Yes, the problem is `mapDispatchToProps` inject a function (or multiple functions) wrapped in `dispatch` into your `props`.

```
import { actionCreator } from './actions

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    actionCreator : () => dispatch(actionCreator)
})
```

Now you have two `actionCreator`, one globally available in the scope (which is your action creator) and `props.actionCreator` which is the original action creator wrapped in `dispatch`. So when you call `actionCreator()` from inside your component it won't throw any errors (cause there is a function named `actionCreator` in the scope, but you will be calling the wrong function, the right one is located at `props.actionCreator`.

> Why do I need to spread the state?

A reducer is a pure function which receives a `state` and `action` and returns the new state. When you just return

```
return {
    isLoggedIn : true
}
```

You're actually overwriting the original state (which contains other properties), so first you need to `spread` the original state to maintain it's structural integrity and them overwrite the properties you want

```
return{
   ...state,
   isLoggedIn : !state.isLoggedIn
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly, would you care to further explain please? first off isn't the point of my `mapDispatchToProps` to be able to use the function right away as I was doing? Also why do I need to spread the state?

Comment: Sure! I'm updating the answer

Comment: Now should make more sense

Answer (score 1):

Redux state is immutable so you need to return a brand new instance of state, change your reducer state to the below.

```
export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE:
       console.log(action);
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
         isLoggedIn: action.value
       });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The key difference there being the

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
         isLoggedIn: action.value
       });
```

Object.assign in the way I'm using it here combines the state object into a brand new object. Check out immutability within redux reducers and I'd recommend adding redux-immutable-state-invariant as a dev package, it can detect when you're directly modifying state and help point out errors like this

Answer (score 0):

Return the state with the new value for `isLoggedIn`. Use the reducer like this:

```
case IS_LOGGED_IN_CHANGE:
  console.log(action);
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggedIn: action.value
  };
```